# Angular safe minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a directive in the following way:

- Directive .html (the template)
- DirectiveController .js  (the controller)
- Directive .js (the directive)

DirectiveController.js:

```
function DirectiveController($scope) {}
```

Directive.js:

```
someModule.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'Directive.html',
        controller: DirectiveController,
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    }
});
```

The question is, how can I minify the DirectiveController?
I cant use the:

```
someModule.controller('someController',['$scope', function($scope) {} ]);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$inject` "annotation":

```
DirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function DirectiveController($scope) {
    ...
}
```

Yes, you *can* put the "annotation" before the function.

Comment: if i understood correctly i could write:
DirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function DirectiveController($s) {
};____ and it would idetify the first parameter as the injected $scope?

Comment: thanks i'll give it a try. will update with the results.